# Can't create diskgroup in Oracle 19c

Tags: oracle, restore, rman

I've successfully installed Oracle 19c with [this article](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=oracle19c&f=6).

Now I need to restore the database from existing backups. I've first restored the control file, then I started to restore the database:

```
rman> restore database;
...
ORA-19504: failed to create file "+DATA"
ORA-17502: ksfdcre:4 Failed to create file +DATA
ORA-15001: diskgroup "DATA" does not exist or is not mounted
ORA-15374: invalid cluster configuration
...
```

Then I tried to create the diskgroup, and it failed:

```
SQL> create diskgroup DATA external redundancy disk '/dev/loop1' force;
create diskgroup DATA external redundancy disk '/dev/loop1' force
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-15000: command disallowed by current instance type
```

Is there a work around? I can either ignore the diskgroup or find a way to create one, I just don't how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are in `RDBMS` instance

to check use the following query:

```
select value from v$parameter where upper(name) = 'INSTANCE_TYPE';
```

or

```
show parameters instance_type
```

If you get `RDBMS` value, go to operational system shell and check the `SID` of ASM instance in `/etc/oratab`

```
cat /etc/oratab
```

After cat the file, you will get something like it:

```
+ASM:/u01/app/19.0.0/grid:N
```

The rows are delimited by `:`. The first field is the `SID` (in my case `+ASM`), the second field is the `GRID_HOME` (also `ORACLE_HOME`)

You can use `oraenv` to set the variables needed to access the ASM instance or you can set the variables manually with `export` command.

With `oraenv`:

```
. oraenv
```

after issuing the `. oraenv` command, type your `SID`

or export the variables manually

```
export ORACLE_SID=+ASM
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/19.0.0/grid
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

NOTE: to create asm diskgroup you need access the instance with `sysasm` role

```
sqlplus / as sysasm
```

Answer (score 0):

I should install `Oracle Database 19c Grid Infrastructure (19.3) for Linux x86-64` first, and setup the diskgroup `DATA`.

Then installed Oracle Database upon it, and rman worked perfectly.

Comment: That is an overkill, you could have just performed the restore to a regular filesystem.